# Opengl - Moving object along (parallel or perpendicular) the view plane

Tags: opengl, geometry

I think I have a unique problem. I have Two objects. One is a cube that is static. I also have a sphere I want to move. My gluLookAt is:

```
float theta = (float) Math.toRadians(yRot); 
float phi = (float) Math.toRadians(xRot);   
glu.gluLookAt(Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta) * cameraMovementRadius, Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta) * cameraMovementRadius, Math.cos(phi) * cameraMovementRadius, 0, 0, 0, Math.cos(theta), Math.sin(theta), 1);
```

This just positions the camera along a spherical path. Now I want to move the sphere always along the view-plane no matter from which angel I am looking at the cube. For example: If I am looking at the cube from: phi = 30 & theta = 85, then the sphere's Forward and backward movement should be perpendicular to view-plane not towards origin (illustrated below).  How do I achieve this? All I am trying to do is to transform the navigation of the sphere.

```
       | 
       |
       | Forward & Backward movement of sphere
       |
       |
---------------- View Plane

(Forward & Backward movement viewed from top)



  ___________ Left & Right movement of sphere


---------------- View Plane

(Forward & Backward movement viewed from top)
```

Update: I was able to achieve forward backward movement by finding the direction vector parallel to the line of sight (camera position and origin). However, I cant do the perpendicular movement. I understand that there are infinite number of perpendicular vector but I just need to move it left or right and up or down. Maybe I am not looking at the problem the right way!?!

Comment: You need to transform then your plane by view matrix

Comment: So the sphere's forward/backward movement is the view direction and left/right the horizontal direction of the view matrix? What's your question?

Comment: Yes. My question is that how do I make that transformation.

Comment: @Michael IV: Can you please elaborate on your answer?